# Which database should I use for my Flutter application?

Tags: database, flutter, backend

I am making an application in Flutter, which requires to save the daily data that the users input in the application. The user has 10 daily actions to do.

The app needs to:

- Save the daily data that the user inputs in those 10 actions.
- Make a daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly summary of the data, divided by each action.

At the start of the development of the app I was thinking of using Firebase, but I feel like it is not the best option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your app only needs to support offline data saving mechanism which not required any internet connectivity then you would use:

- [Isar](https://isar.dev/) (It is a no-sql/non-relational local/offline database which has interactive inspector editor)
- [Object Box](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) (It is a no-sql/non-relational local/offline database)
- [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) (It is a no-sql/non-relational local/offline database)
- [Sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) (It is a sql/relational local/offline database)
- [Drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) (It is a sql/relational local/offline database which is build on top of sqlite)

Otherwise you can use:

- [Firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) (It is a no-sql/non-relational online backend as a service)
- [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/) (It is a cloud based backend as a service)
- [Parse Server](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk_flutter) (It is a kind of sql/relational online backend as a service)
- [Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/) (It is a no-sql/non-relational mongodb based online backend as a service)
- [AppWrite](https://pub.dev/packages/appwrite) (It is a no-sql/non-relational online backend as a service)
- [Supabase](https://supabase.com/) (It is an online backend as a service)

If you want to write dart based custom backend:

- [Dart Frog](https://dartfrog.vgv.dev/) (It is a minimalistic backend framework)
- [Serverpod](https://serverpod.dev/) (It is a sql based backend framework)

If you comes from Java/Native Android or React Native background:

- [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot/) (It is a Java based enterprise level backend framework)
- [Nest JS](https://nestjs.com/) (It is a progressive Node JS based reliable backend framework)

According to your provided information, I think [Firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) or [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/) (for online backend as a service) and [Isar](https://isar.dev/) (for local db and for flutter web support use [Sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or [Drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) instead of Isar) would be good option.

Comment: Hive is deprecated

Comment: You can use object box no sql storage. It is very fast for query.

Comment: Yes now I am using Object Box

Comment: Yes, avoid Hive! It will delete your data unexpectedly. Loads of open issues on github.  I did not realise hive was deprecated because it still has 100% popularity on pub.dev.

Comment: I went with Isar and regretted it. I'm going with drift because it uses SQLite under the hood which is tried and tested. A little more work to set up but Isar and Hive are a bit of a mess, with no web support even though it says it does.

Comment: Oh, actually I never used isar or hive for flutter web.

Comment: @KunalKalwar.. Hive is not deprecated

Comment: @dayvedev I see its updated