Flutter relational database (local)
I would like to store data in a local database, where i would like to have model classes with relations to each other, e.g.
class Member {
int id;
String name;
List<Documents> documents}

class Document {
int id;
String docType;
String path;
}

I would like to store, update and get entries in the db with the relations. When i have a member with a list of documents set i would like to have a function which persists the member in its table and the documents in their table (with foreign keys)...
Could some give me hint which way to go, what technology to use? And point me to some documentation, examples?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530075/which-database-should-i-use-for-my-flutter-application
